# Strange behavior when returning view with custom Blade directive in Laravel

Tags: laravel, view, render, laravel-blade, directive

Currently I am working on a project where views need to be rendered through a custom Blade directive. However I came across a few (limitations?) errors I cannot solve (for a long time).

My custom Blade directive with tree different ways to output a view.

```
Blade::directive('lwField', function ($expression) {

    // 1
    return view('lw::module.field.field')->render();

    // 2
    return Blade::compileString('{!! view("lw::module.field.field")->render() !!}');

    // 3
    return Blade::compileString('@include("lw::module.field.field")');

});
```

The field view:

```
Get to the choppa!
```

The main view:

```
@extends('layout.default')

@section('main_content')

    @lwField()

@endsection
```

The layout file:

```
// ... some cool html

@section ('main_content') 

@show

// ... even more cool html
```

The following happens when I execute the three methods separately:

**1** `return view('lw::module.field.field')->render();`

The fist time it executes it throws an error:

```
include(/somepath/storage/framework/views/b30c24f5b8fd420ef1a08edb52e92174e2dfe911.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /somepath/resources/views/page/default.blade.php)
```

This is true since there is only one view in my cached folder:

```
// 5b27802352643346357e49b847d934736c36cd07.php
// The main view with the field view
<?php $__env->startSection('main_content'); ?>

    Get to the choppa!

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
```

The second time I run this it magically works. It will generate 3 other files:

```
// b30c24f5b8fd420ef1a08edb52e92174e2dfe911.php
// the main view with yielding layout view without field view
<?php $__env->startSection('main_content'); ?>

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make('layout.default', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>

// e4cec91e7d4adb5dac5c63e5bfa85ba9a258f664.php
// the layout file
// ...
<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getFirstLoop(); ?>
// ...

// ffd60653d8490007c272c527abef3a5ede092a33.php
// layout view and main view
// ...
<?php $__env->startSection('main_content'); ?>

<?php echo $__env->yieldSection(); ?>
// ...
```

It looks like it generates two files that are the same but one without the field view.

**2** `return Blade::compileString('{!! view("lw::module.field.field")->render() !!}');`

**3** `return Blade::compileString('@include("lw::module.field.field")');`

These methods will return a blanko page and generate two files in cache without showing/logging any errors.

```
// 5b27802352643346357e49b847d934736c36cd07.php
// Field view
Get to the choppa!

// b30c24f5b8fd420ef1a08edb52e92174e2dfe911.php
// Main view and field view
<?php $__env->startSection('main_content'); ?>

    <?php echo view("lw::module.field.field")->render(); ?>

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
```

This method will not generate the layout file.

Does anyone have a clue on what is happening. Maybe this kind of behavior is not strange at all and this is how Blade should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on a project that required me to do the same thing, the problem is that making a new Blade directive is not a good practice when you want to render another view, It's because of the Cache, every Blade directive is being cached so if you want to render dynamic data it will cause you a lot of problems.

Since I have tried a lot of options and you want to render another view file and not just push html to the blade directive, I suggest you to make a new helper or even a service that you can pass there the parameters and it will return the render function that outputs clean HTML so this way you can be sure that your content will be always dynamic and won't be cached.

### TL;DR

**Example:**

In your helpers functions file put:

```
function render_my_view() {
    return view(''lw::module.field.field'')->render();
}
```

So then in yout blade file you can use:

```
{!! render_my_view() !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try that!

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. However I used custom Blade directive to parse my files and retrieve the fields to show the user, think about a CMS. My idea was to make it easy for the developers by declaring fields and sections for certain pages only in the view. Now need to rewrite my parser :( :). Big thanks anyway!!

Comment: Also I used Blade directive to retrieve `get_defined_vars()` passed to the main view by the controller.  Since the rendering doesn't happen in the view anymore I have to find another method to solve this. Any suggestions? I think about using `Blade::compose`.

Comment: You can pass the variables to the helper function: example: {!! render_my_view(get_defined_vars()) !!}

Comment: I know, I just don't want to bother a developer to do that every time. It need to be automatic. I fixed it bij using `View::composer()`